# gnuplot command every on row only

Tags: csv, 3d, gnuplot

I have a matrix listed in a `.csv` file of approximately 0.6 mio datapoints I would like to visualize in a 3d plot. Since my computer showed troubles with the amount of data I evolved the command line from:

```
splot "file.csv" matrix w pm3d
```

to

```
splot "file.csv" matrix every 5::50::3000 w pm3d
```

My intention was to only plot from row 50 to 3000 using only every 5th row. A row contains 100 columns btw. The command however cut the first 50 rows and columns, using every 5th row and column and ended in with line 3500.

How do I use the every command on my rows only?

I also tried to combine the using command with the every command in order to define my row with the every command but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Use

```
splot "file.csv" matrix every :5::50::3000 w pm3d
```

Long answer: The description of the `every` option is:

```
plot ’file’ every {<point_incr>}
                    {:{<block_incr>}
                      {:{<start_point>}
                        {:{<start_block>}
                          {:{<end_point>}
                            {:<end_block>}}}}}
```

The description of `point` and `block` refers to the usual data file structure, where two data *blocks* are separated by an empty line.

When using the `matrix` data format, replace `point` by `column` and `block` by `row`. That means, that `every 1:1` selects all points, `every 2:1` selects every second column and every row, `every 1:2` (or `every :2`) selects every column and every second row.

Just use a simple data file

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
file0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and test:

```
splot 'file' matrix with lines, '' every :2
```